# How to log JDBC/Hibernate Transactions Duration?

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, jboss

I'm using jboss 4.2 with Hibernate.
i need to log transactions duration, so I have statistics on the average time it takes a transaction to complete or rollback.
another issue I have is jboss JTA (arjuna) aborting long running transactions, so I need to know what timeout to configure there.

Comment: What is your Hibernate version? Some versions of Hibernate can gather statistics themselves. Or you can use an AOP framework.

Comment: Hibernate version is 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a timer that will count the time between the transaction start and end. A possibility to achieve this can be:

```
EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.createEntityManager(); //I used JPA's EntityManager instead of hibernate's sessions. createEntityManager iss a function created by you.
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
Date startDate = new Date();

//... your DB stuff goes here ...

tx.commit();
Date endDate = new Date();

MyLogger.logTransactionDuration(startDate, endDate);
```

In the above snippet of code, I make you the idea of how you can achieve this.

If you want, you can use `log4j` or `slf4j` api, and you would to make only some settings in `log4j.properties` file.

Hope to help.

Comment: I am looking to a 'no coding' solution, something which is already supported by Hibernate or jboss JTA.